# Build errors of Appium Android test

Tags: java, android, appium

I am a beginner of Appium and Java. When I perform my first demo for Android test, I just get 2 errors and have no idea how to fix them after google. So I have to find some help here.
Code:

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

public class AutoTest {

private AndroidDriver<WebElement> driver;

@Before
public void Setup() throws MalformedURLException{
    //File classPathRoot = new java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    //File appDir = new File(classPathRoot,"app/login.apk");


    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "emulator-5554");
    capabilities.setBrowserName("Android");
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "6.0.1");
    capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.ANDROID);
    //capabilities.setCapability("app", appDir.getAbsolutePath());
    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.study.kukaka.login");
    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "LoginActivity");

    driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723"),capabilities);

}

@Test
public void test() {
    driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("myemail@hotmail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("whatever");
    driver.findElement(By.id("email_sign_in_button")).click();
    System.out.println("Test pass!");
    }

@After
public void End(){
    driver.quit();
}

 }
```

And the errors:

1. The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder. Fix the build path then try building this project
2. The type org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

The library I used is as below.
[Library I used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kirGY.png)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Remove at least one jar file either selenium stand alone or selenium jar file

Answer (score 0):

You may need to selenium remote driver jar file to build path. ( I could not seen it your build path )
Download from maven 
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-remote-driver/2.44.0
and put it to your build path. If not works again, putting error logs will be more heplfull.

Comment: Thank you. i fixed it by replacing selenium JARs including server and client with version 2.53.0.